# Statistical validity of performing t-tests on indices of value ranges?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, survey, paired-data

I'm trying to perform a t-test on some paired data. The data values are not meant to be interpreted directly, they are actually the indices of ranges of values. For example:

The ranges might be: 1-3, 4-6, 7-9

And the ranges would be represented by: 1, 2, 3

Is it statistically valid to use the range indices (1, 2, 3) rather than the ranges themselves (1-3, 4-6, 7-9) or at least some value that is more representative of them (eg. the range midpoint: 2, 5, 8)?

Does the answer change if the ranges being referred to are non-uniform, non-sequential, or only bounded on one side?

Additionally, because the t-test can be used to find the difference of the means between distributions, how do you interpret that value if you are using range indices? I.e. What do you do when the mean difference is non-integer and all your range indices are integers?

For some context, the data is survey results before and after a trial, with the indices referring to question answers (multiple choice questions that use ranges of values). The null hypothesis is that the mean difference of the before and after distributions is zero.

Thanks very much for any help you can give!

Comment: Ask yourself: Is mean of the indices meaningful? If not, then why would you want to compare such means? What exactly is your data? What hypothesis do you want to test?

Comment: The data is survey results before and after a trial, with the indices referring to question answers (multiple choice questions that use ranges of values). The null hypothesis is that the mean difference of the before and after distributions is zero. As for your first two questions, that's the part I'm having difficulty answering. I don't know whether or not the mean of the indices is useful or even if use of indices in t-tests is statistically valid.

Comment: Welch's test is for two independent samples. If your samples have pairing it won't be suitable.

Comment: @Glen_b My mistake. I've edited my question to indicate that I am in fact just using a paired t-test. However, even knowing that I am still unsure of my interpretation.